# Incorrect fuel injectors - How much damage can they do?

Tags: fuel-injection

I'm considering buying a car (2001 MR-S w/ 2zz-ge swap) that had incorrect injectors installed into 2 of 4 cylinders. Specifically, 260cc injectors were installed instead of the 320cc injectors it needed.

What damage can be caused by driving a car with incorrect injectors, and what symptoms may be noticeable in a car that has experienced this?

Also, if injectors are incorrect, is it worse to have injectors that supply too much fuel or too little fuel?

Comment: I'd guess if it hasn't been tuned for the bigger injectors,you run the risk of the associated cylinders running lean.

Comment: I think the ecu will notice the lean mixture from the o2 sensor and try rich-ing it as best as it could, of course the stock ones now will be rich and if the engine was to be put under high load the other 2 sensors wouldn't be enough for the demand and thus their cylinders will be lean.